# Integration by substitution - question about finding an expression for du or dx

Tags: calculus

The exercise is as follows: Find $$\int {x^3 \over \sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$

I know theres more than one possibility when I'm choosing my core $u$. When reading the solution for this problem, they've chosen $u=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ . That means we get $u^2=x^2+1$ and $x^2=u^2-1$. Inserting $u$ in the expression we get $$\int {(u^2-1)x \over u}dx$$ Now in the solution they find that $2xdx=2udu$ and then $xdx=udu$.Normally I'd have no trouble finding an expression for $dx$ or $du$, but this time I can't find out what I'm supposed to do. Could anyone please explain to me how they find that $2xdx=2udu$?

Comment: $x^2 = u^2 - 1$ -> $2 x dx = 2 u du$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remember the rule for figuring out what $d(f(t))$ means.  The rule is $d(f(t)) = f'(t)dt$.

So starting with $u^2=x^2+1$, we have $$u^2=x^2+1 \\ \implies d(u^2)=d(x^2+1) \\ \frac{d(u^2)}{du}du=\frac{d(x^2+1)}{dx}dx \\ 2udu=2xdx$$

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't think of that rule for some reason. Thanks.