# Question about finding $du$ from $dx$ when integrating by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, substitution

**Example 1:**

$$\int\frac{\tan^2(\ln x)}{x}dx$$

*Method 1:*

$$\text{Let}\ u=\ln x$$

$$\implies du=d(\ln x)$$

$$\implies du=\ln'(x)dx$$

$$\implies du=\frac{1}{x}dx$$

*Method 2:*

$$\text{Let}\ u=\ln x\tag{Start}$$

$$\implies \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\implies xdu=dx$$

$$\implies du=\frac{dx}{x}\tag{End}$$

**Example 2**

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-1}}$$

*Method 1:*

$$\text{Let}\ x^4=\frac{1}{u^2}$$

$$\implies u=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$\implies du=d(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

$$\implies du=d(x^{-2})$$

$$\implies du=-2x^{-3}dx$$

*Method 2:*

$$\text{Let}\ x^4=\frac{1}{u^2}\tag{Start}$$

$$\implies 4x^3=-2u^{-3}\frac{du}{dx}$$

$$\implies 2x^3=-u^{-3}\frac{du}{dx}$$

$$\implies 2x^3dx=-u^{-3}du$$

$$\implies du=-\frac{2x^3dx}{u^{-3}}$$

$$\implies du=-\frac{2x^3dx}{(\frac{1}{x^2})^{-3}}$$

$$\implies du=-2x^{-3}dx\tag{End}$$

**Questions:**

1. In both examples 1 and 2, in method 1, I just used this the rule $d(f(t)) = f'(t)dt$. However, in method 2, I used differentiation in both sides, cross multiplication, dividing both sides by $x$, other general rules we use in equations etc. I'm certain that method 1 is correct. In both method 1 and 2, I got the same end expression, so the result of method 2 is also correct. However, are the intermediate lines between the start and the end correct in method 2? I'm asking this because I used cross multiplication and other techniques; I managed to arrive at the correct answer, but I'm anxious whether the intermediate lines are correct to write or not i.e. is LHS=RHS true in those lines.

---

Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1537224/768162),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4371390/768162)

Comment: The method 2, strictly speaking, is not correct, since $du$ and $dx$ are differentials, and the expression $du/dx$ is not a quotient of differentials (quotient of differentials does not make any sense). However it works because this notation is amazing. I recommend you to learn about differential forms defined on surfaces (or manifolds), and its "pull-backs". And you will see this in a more natural way.

Comment: @Ted "However it works because this notation is amazing"- it works as in all the intermediate lines between the start and end are correct i.e. LHS=RHS is true for those lines?

Comment: I would say that both methods are correct.  In nonstandard analysis there is no problem with differentials being values.  It gets more complicated in higher-order differentials (because we tend to use bad notation for the second derivative), but, for first derivatives, there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for why you want to find a $\mathrm{d}u$ from a $\mathrm{d}x$ is in reality because you have the substitution theorem which tells you that, simply put,

$$\int f(u(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}u(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int f(u)\mathrm{d}u.$$

Thus what you do in reality when you do a substitution, i.e. there is no actual fraction which you can cancel things in. However this theorem tells you that you can essentially treat it like a fraction when you do a substitution, but formally it is your second method which is more along the lines of what is actually going on.